# Looking for software that can play chords while I play lead

Tags: software-rec, music

This question is for musicians / guitarists.

I'm looking for some software that can play chords in a loop, while I play the lead. I could record the rhythm manually, and overlay it, but I'm having latency issues with my input device. So some synthesized rhythm would work.

Looking for something that sounds like an acoustic guitar. It should be able to play all major / minor chords as well as sus, 2,5,7ths - you name it.

I want to setup a song pattern, and then reply it, while I play lead.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Band In A Box](http://www.band-in-a-box.com/)

Comment: Looks good, I'll need to check it out. Thanks for link.